# Pandas Plot: scatter plot with index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a scatter plot from pandas dataframe, and I dont want to use matplotlib plt for it. Following is the script

```
df:
group people value
   1    5    100
   2    2    90
   1    10   80
   2    20   40
   1    7    10
```

I want to create a scatter plot with index on x axis, only using pandas datframe

```
df.plot.scatter(x = df.index, y = df.value)
```

it gives me an error

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64') not in index
```

I dont want to use

```
plt.scatter(x = df.index, y = df.value)
```

how to perfom this plot with pandas dataframe

Comment: Try df.plot.scatter(x = df.index.tolist(), y = df.value)

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: Sheldore's suggestion doesn't work as plot.scatter() takes the _names_ of columns not the _list of values_. The OP's initial dataframe doesn't show any index column, but @anky's answer provides a solution which also saves the faff of matplotlib.

Answer (score 16):

You can try and use:

```
df.reset_index().plot.scatter(x = 'index', y = 'value')
```

[image]

Comment: This does work because the `reset_index()` function makes a new column from the old unnamed index and calls it `index` by default which is then recognised by `plot.scatter()`

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing two styles, `matplotlib` and the `pandas` interface to it. Either do it like [@anky_91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840637/anky-91) suggested in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169695/4042267), or use `matplotlib` directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df.index, df.value)
plt.xlabel("index")
plt.ylabel("value")
plt.show()
```

[image]